# Изображение не сразу появляется

Tags: javascript, html, css, img

Использую Angular js 1.6.9 , angular page loader, particleground. После исчезновения прелоадера картинка появляется только если нажать на f11 или f12.

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Приведите пример кода.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/XRm7jKqK это главная страница из которой открывается страница где есть див где бекраундом стоит изображение которое не сразу открывается (извините за такое оформление ибо я с телефона )

Comment: Код необходимо привести в вопросе. Выкиньте из него все лишнее, что не влияет на проблему. Оформите сниппетом. Вот увидите, после этого сразу появится ответ! Может, даже сами в процессе создания примера найдете ошибку)